# Apache QPID JMS Client - setting prefetch doesn't work

Tags: java, jms, amqp, azureservicebus, qpid

I have a `JmsConnectionFactory` configured with a URI such as this:

`failover:(amqps://11.22.33.44?amqp.idleTimeout=120000&transport.tcpKeepAlive=true&jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10)?failover.maxReconnectAttempts=20`

Note the `jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10` parameter, which according to the official [documentation](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.27.0/docs/index.html)

> ... controls how many messages the remote peer can
>   send to the client and be held in a prefetch buffer for each consumer
>   instance.

So I shouldn't see more than 10 messages buffered in the client, right? Well, that doesn't work.

I've ended up using reflection to periodically print the `MessageQueue.size()` of each `JmsMessageConsumer`:

```
MessageConsumer messageConsumer = ...
Field field = JmsMessageConsumer.class.getDeclaredField("messageQueue");
field.setAccessible(true);
MessageQueue q = (MessageQueue) field.get(messageConsumer);
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println(q.size()), 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And when my message handler is slow (or blocked), I see queue sizes of slightly less than 1000 messages, which is the default prefetch size.

So - is this a bug? And how do I go about setting a different prefetch size?

I'm using `qpid-jms-client`, version `0.27.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI is incorrect, it should be:

```
failover://(amqps://11.22.33.44?amqp.idleTimeout=120000&transport.tcpKeepAlive=true)
    ?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10&failover.maxReconnectAttempts=20
```

The JMS options are global so they are applied to the outermost part of the URI along with the failover options.  The wrapped AMQP connection URIs contain only transport options that control each specific connection.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I'll try it out later.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

`JmsConnectionFactory` has a `JmsPrefetchPolicy`. I don't see how it's supposed to be set using a URI parameter, but it can be set using `JmsConnectionFactory.setPrefetchPolicy()` like this:

```
JmsConnectionFactory cf = ...
JmsDefaultPrefetchPolicy prefetchPolicy = new JmsDefaultPrefetchPolicy();
prefetchPolicy.setAll(123); // Set prefetch size here
cf.setPrefetchPolicy(prefetchPolicy);
```

Haven't seen this documented anywhere.